# Cocos2d runAction: on UIView

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, wrapper

Is it possible to run a cocos2d action like `[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.3 scale:1.1]` on a UIView? I know it's possible to wrap a UIView into a CCNode so you can add it as a child to a layer, but I have no idea as to *how*. Could anyone shed some light here? Thanks!

Edit: I've looked at `CCUIViewWrapper` but have had a few issues with it, namely that a) running actions on a wrapped UIView causes it to disappear and b) buttons lose their 'pushable' functionality; they're selectors aren't fired and their highlighted state isn't shown. But other than that it's great :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually had to just use the Core Graphics equivalents to the Cocos animations when animating the UIView, and it worked well enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CCUIViewWrapper

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/22898

Comment: I've seen it. I've had a few problems with it. I'll revise the question.